# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat9

Whenever i run my spring-jdbc project and i entere the url in my browser i get this HTTP error , i want to know if my mapping is wrong ,because i am not able to pinpoint the error in my code.

RestController.java

```java
public class RestControllerTest {

    @Test(timeout = 30000000)
    public void testCreateRide(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Ride ride=new Ride();
        ride.setName("Indoor run");
        ride.setDuration(60);

        restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/ride",ride);
        System.out.println(" "+ride);
    }
    @Test(timeout= 2000000)
    public void testGetRide(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Ride ride;
        ride=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/ride/1",Ride.class);
        System.out.println(" Ride name : "+ride.getName());
    }
    @Test(timeout=30000000)
    public void testUpdateRide(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Ride ride;
        ride=restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/ride/1",Ride.class);
        ride.setDuration(ride.getDuration() + 1);


        restTemplate.put("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/ride",ride);
        System.out.println(" Ride name : "+ride.getName());
    }
    @Test(timeout= 2000000)
    public void testBatchUpdate(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Ride ride;
        restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/batch",Object.class);
    }
    @Test(timeout= 2000000)
    public void testDelete(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.delete("http://localhost:8080/ride_tracker/delete/5");

    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class RideController {

    @Autowired
    private RideService rideService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/ride",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody Ride createRide(@RequestBody Ride ride){
        return rideService.createRide(ride);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rides", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Ride> getRides() {
        return rideService.getRides();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/ride/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Ride getRide(@PathVariable(value="id") Integer id){
        return rideService.getRide(id);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ride",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody Ride updateRide(@RequestBody Ride ride){
        return rideService.updateRide(ride);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/batch",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object batch(){
        rideService.batch();
        return null;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/delete/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody Object delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id ){
        rideService.deleteRide(id);
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is far too little information here to be able to answer it.

Comment: @Av11 please add your exception stack-trace and config.

Comment: Also instead of creating RestTemplate every time, use config to create Bean and autowire wherever required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.